# Как скачать sql от Mysql с Php?

Tags: php, mysql

Как скачать sql от Mysql с Php?
Почему меняете вопрос на ваш ответь? Я не задавал такой вопрос
Мне нужно скачать sql как файл. Ну копия скачать как обяснить этого незнаю

Если будете сменять вопрос буду удалять вопрос

Answer (score 1):

Выполнить запрос резервного копирования базы данных из файла PHP. Ниже приведен пример использования запроса SELECT INTO OUTFILE для создания резервной копии таблицы:

```php
<?php
$DB_HOST = "localhost";
$DB_USER = "xxx";
$DB_PASS = "xxx";
$DB_NAME = "xxx";

$con = new mysqli($DB_HOST, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS, $DB_NAME);
if($con->connect_errno > 0) {
  die('Connection failed [' . $con->connect_error . ']');
}

$tableName  = 'yourtable';
$backupFile = 'backup/yourtable.sql';
$query      = "SELECT * INTO OUTFILE '$backupFile' FROM $tableName";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
?>
```

Чтобы восстановить резервную копию, вам просто нужно выполнить запрос LOAD DATA INFILE следующим образом:

```php
<?php
$DB_HOST = "localhost";
$DB_USER = "xxx";
$DB_PASS = "xxx";
$DB_NAME = "xxx";

$con = new mysqli($DB_HOST, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS, $DB_NAME);
if($con->connect_errno > 0) {
  die('Connection failed [' . $con->connect_error . ']');
}

$tableName  = 'yourtable';
$backupFile = 'yourtable.sql';
$query      = "LOAD DATA INFILE 'backupFile' INTO TABLE $tableName";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
?>
```

Оригинал: [Export MySQL database using PHP only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22195493/export-mysql-database-using-php-only)

Comment: раз вы поняли, о чём в вопросе речь, отредактируйте его, приведя в понятное для других состояние. такие действия, кстати, поощряются: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/90/explainer

Comment: @EminChannel так там вывод в файл же идет `backupFile`. Посмотрите в документации куда упадет файл.

Comment: @EminChannel, мой предыдущий комментарий адресован автору ответа — mepihindeveloper

Comment: @EminChannel напишите тогда отправку файла с помощью `header()`. Это уже другой вопрос не по теме. Например: https://xn--d1acnqm.xn--j1amh/%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B8/php-%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-url